# Flattening/re-structuring array returned from API

Tags: php, arrays

I've got an array being returned from a shipping API that returns the following:

```
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Next day',
    'serviceLevel' => 'nextday',
    'orderedProduct' => '220',
    'deliveryWindowStart' => '08:00',
    'deliveryWindowEnd' => '20:00',
    'servicePoint' => true,
    'sortOrder' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Next day 12:00',
    'serviceLevel' => 'am',
    'orderedProduct' => '221',
    'deliveryWindowStart' => '08:00',
    'deliveryWindowEnd' => '12:00',
    'servicePoint' => false,
    'sortOrder' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'Next day 10:30',
    'serviceLevel' => 'tenThirtyAm',
    'orderedProduct' => '222',
    'deliveryWindowStart' => '08:00',
    'deliveryWindowEnd' => '10:30',
    'servicePoint' => false,
    'sortOrder' => 3,
  )
```

Can anyone help with how I get this "down" to the following, as I'm having trouble removing the iteration and "collapsing" the array. I'd like the output to be:

`array ('serviceLevel' => 'name', 'serviceLevel' => 'name')`

which would equate to:

`array ('next day' => 'Next day', 'am' => 'Next day 12:00', 'tenThirtyAm' => 'Next day 10:30')`

I'm using Laravel if that helps, I've tried splitting the array down and rebuilding it but always end up with the services separated into their own array. From here it does into a drop down form field and so I end up with double the amount of form options I need currently, as there's "0, Next day, 1, Next day 12:00" and so on.

Comment: `$newArray = []; foreach($arrayFromApi as $elem) { $newArray[$elem['serviceLevel']] = $elem['name']; }` ...?

Comment: Or use a combination of [array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine) and two times [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)?